# How to find density? (Changing units)

Tags: physics, fluid-dynamics

I have a 10 kg/m^2 weight load for a steel sheet and I would like to calculate the density of the steel sheet.Is it possible to calculate the density of the steel sheet using the value of 10 kg/m^2 weight load?

I have tried calculating value for density by multiplying by the area (m^2) of the steel sheet, then dividing by the volume of the steel sheet which gives units of kg/m^3. However when I change the size of the area or volume for example, my density value will change? Shouldn't the density be constant for a material.

How can I calculate the density from 10 kg/^2? (If it is possible)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you be more specific about your question? I have no sense of the physical situation that you are describing.

Comment: @Tucker sorry, updated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the thickness of the sheet, which will give you the factor of length that you need.  Yes, the density should be constant.  [Typical densities of steel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steel) range from $7750$ to $8050$ kg/m$^3$, which says your sheet is about $\frac {10}{7900}$meters thick.

Comment: I am finding that the density will change as the thickness varies, area stays the same, hence volume increases (due to thickness increase) and therefore the density will change? Does that sound correct?

Comment: If you are thinking of holding the areal density constant, that would be correct.  What is constant in reality is the material density.  The areal density of $10 kg/m^2 is the product of the material density and the thickness.  If you double the thickness the areal density will double.